# Standard Object Edit Modal Doesn't Scroll and makes unusable

Tags: standard-objects, modal, edit

I have clients that have had issues and I can not recreate them or find any information on why this would happen.

I have a 2GP package that clients install and when they are looking at a standard Salesforce object (Contact, Account), they click edit, and the modal that pops up to display all the fields seems to be overflowing the whole page and there is no scroll bar. There are a lot of fields that show up - but all testing and during development it has been fine because it scrolls, and works great.

I have tested this on multiple browsers (and incognito mdoe) and OS's and I can't replicate it. I have tried various record types, screen sizes, etc and I can't replicate it. I am very lost so asking if anyone here knows how to fix this or why this is happening...?

Again - this is not a custom modal at all. It is when they click the basic Edit button on a Standard Salesforce object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to have a client show me the issue and apparently styles from a modal that I was creating in a different part of my package would load its styles and overwrite the modal styles to all modals. Only some of the time.

What a weird issue.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little to show waht was overriding? Could be the style names or something